# Как бы вы улучшили реализацию задачи?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Решая задачи по программированию, решил такую как "Трибоначчи". Трибоначчи, это как фибоначчи, только используются три последних чисел, т.е. `0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4`.

Мой алгоритм таков:

> К результату для начала добавляем начальную сигнатуру (0, 0, 1) к результату. После чего, запоминаем сумму трех последних чисел результата (0 + 0 + 1 = 1). Далее, значению первого элемента последовательности последних трёх чисел присваиваем значение второго элемента. Значению второго элемента присваиваем значение третьего элемента. Значению третьего элемента присваиваем сумму трех последних чисел результата (т.е. 1), и так до конца.

Я бы хотел, чтобы вы улучшили мой следующий код и дали советы. Спасибо:

```cs
List<double> result = new();
var currentSequence = new double[3];
currentSequence = signature[0..3];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  if (i < 3)
  {
    result.Add(signature[i]);
    continue;
  }
  double nextNumber = currentSequence.Sum();
  result.Add(nextNumber);
  currentSequence[0] = currentSequence[1];
  currentSequence[1] = currentSequence[2];
  currentSequence[2] = nextNumber;
}
return result.ToArray();
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8

Comment: А вам точно нужно весь ряд запоминать? Обычно в задачах требуется только значение N-того числа в ряду.

Comment: @DmitryK,  да, конкретно моя задача запросила целый ряд с длиной до значения N.

Comment: Ну тогда тут улучшать нечего. :)

Comment: @DmitryK, спасибо) Просто всегда ищу критику для своего кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> конкретно моя задача запросила целый ряд с длиной до значения N

Ну, тогда нет смысла держать два разных массива — вычисления имеет смысл проводить сразу в целевом массиве. Я C#, увы, не знаю, но на C++ это было бы примерно так:

```
int * result = new int [N+1];  // Кстати, почему у вас `double`? Если последовательность
                               // сугубо целочисленная...
result[0] = result[1] = 0;
result[2] = 1;
for(int i = 3; i <= N; ++i) result[i] = result[i-3] + result[i-2] + result[i-1];
```

Все, на выходе готовый массив со всеми числами трибоначчи, без каких-то лишних массивов и промежуточных вычислений. Думаю, что на С# будет выглядеть точно так же.

Comment: Я точно так же сделал, горжусь собой. Скоро догоню Вас, будьте осторожны. С наступающим 200к

Comment: Такой код выглядит брутально)
`Кстати, почему у вас `double?`

Меня самого это смутило, но если бы я всё поменял на int[], в тестах тоже пришлось бы копаться. А некоторые тесты вообще нельзя было редактировать. Спасибо большое за ответ, пока буду изучать его в доль и поперёк.

Comment: @アオクシ если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа.